# macOS application for showing external HDD usage?

Tags: macos, hard-disk

I'm planning on selling a used external HDD on eBay.  Are there any applications for macOS out there (preferably free) that can show me the usage statistics for the drive so that I can let potential buyers know its condition more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS' file manager should have this ability you're asking for